# How to handle images in j2me like .dat format

Tags: java-me

I am developing a game in j2me. How to handle images in .dat format.

I downloaded some games and extracted jar , found some dat format images and not able to open that images and images size also very less.. what tools I need to use?

Ref link
[enter link description here](https://www.coderanch.com/t/227519/JME/Mobile/Images-Games)

Not able to find solution?

Answer (score 0):

A dat file could be anything. Depends what the developer felt like doing.

Some developers chose to strip PNG files of their header, and added the header back in the code. This was partly done in order to save a few bytes (because they mattered back then), and partly because of the challenge in doing it like that, and partly because it ensured all images used the exact same palette.

So that's one possibility, but it really could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by mr_lou, there really isn't anything special about a .dat extension.

The steps to re-compile a file usually start with opening the file up in a hex editor and then looking at the first bits of information in the file. You then basically work from there to re-compile the data necessary for a 'normal' program to interpret the file. In particular, the first 8-16 bytes are often very helpful for determining what type of file it is "supposed" to be.

If you are looking at a png file (that's what I usually prefer to use for art assets) then you can reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics to see how a 'normal' png might look. When you're tweaking to save bytes you often strip unnecessary fields from png headers (things like the ancillary chunks) and using a common palette.

However, remember that it's not necessarily image data. It could be things like level data, sound, default stats or any particular amount of stuff.